# Dagger2 androidTest error duplicate entry: javax/annotation/Generated.class

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger2 for DI. My project has 2 modules, a `:common` module which is a library and an `:app` module which is the actual application.

In the library module I have `AndroidApp` which extends `MultiDexApplication` and is inherited in `:app` module. I have followed Google's dagger2 [example](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs) to add DI with Dagger2.

Each time I run the app I get the following message as an error:

```
Android/common/src/main/java/com/common/AndroidApp.java:10: The import com.common.di.DaggerAndroidAppComponent cannot be resolved.
```

but the weird part is that Android Studio says `BUILD SUCESSFULL` and the app runs without problems.

When I try to run tests (androidTest) on the `:common` library module I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':common:packageAllDebugAndroidTestClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: javax/annotation/Generated.class
```

I'm assuming there is no connection between these 2 errors, but does anyone have any idea on what's going on and how to fix the tests?

Answer (score 0):

After I updated the gradle plugin to 1.2.3 the issues stopped showing up. Weird.

Comment: Weird it's happening for me in 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'